# Is there a faster way to calculate the mean value of function results than generate/accumulate?

Tags: c++, return-value, mean

This is about calculating the arithmetic mean of the return values of a function.

To get a mean of `N` function calls, I have thought of:

```
std::vector<double> results(N);
std::generate(results.begin(), results.end(), my_function(...));
double mean = std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), 0.0) / N;
```

Is there a standard/modern C++ way to do it faster or omit the intermediate vector? Boost is also an option.

Comment: That's not the mean, it's the average you're calculating. And for that you have to sum all values, there's no shortcut (unless it's acceptable with an approximate (and possibly wrong) value instead).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That _is_ the definition of the mean.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg An **arithmetic mean** means average

Comment: @JoachimPileborg maybe you "mean" the "median"? I want the arithmetic mean, aka average.

Comment: Okay, mistook the terms, but the rest of my comment still stands. :)

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_input_iterator.html

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), 0) / N;` gets the sum of the vector doesn't it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Maybe there's a way to just keep one value, keep track of the current iteration count, and just update the one value accordingly? I have looked in the std algorithm library but found nothing.

Comment: Just use a library with proper C or C++ interface that uses SIMD under the hood.

Comment: @T.C. better? Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You're all being mean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the function `N` times but you can save some space doing calculations on the fly:

```
double mean = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    mean += my_function(...);
mean /= N;
```

Update: possible *modern* one-line approach using boost:

```
double mean = std::accumulate(
    boost::make_function_input_iterator(my_func, 0),
    boost::make_function_input_iterator(my_func, N), 0.0) / N;
```

Comment: The OP asked for a **modern** C++ way to achieve this. A hand-written loop does not feel very modern. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - No, making simple stuff complicated is very modern :-)

Comment: A range based for-loop will be modern by constructing ranges without container :)

Comment: @knivil There is no range to loop on.  The OP needs to call a function N times.

Comment: `ranges::accumulate(ranges::view::generate_n([]{ return my_function(...); }, N), 0.0) / N;`, FWIW

Comment: @4386427 The problem is comments are for commenting, not for answering. The site relies on answers being posted as such.

Comment: @FelixDombek Because range-v3 is neither standard nor in boost. It's mostly to answer the "there is no range" comment.

Comment: The docs for `make_function_input_iterator` have an example with input state `0` to `10`, saying "counts from 0 to 10". Does someone know about inclusive/exclusive `10`?

Comment: @FelixDombek it's non-inclusive. The `State` object (that is counter in this case) is incremented after each iteration, and so when it becomes equal to `N`, the iterator becomes equal to the second argument of `std::accumulate`, and it finishes.

Answer (score 2):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3):

```
auto mean = ranges::accumulate(
                    ranges::view::generate_n([]{ return my_function(...); }, N),
                    0.0) / N;
```

Comment: Is this faster than the solution suggested by @AntonSavin?

Comment: @4386427 - The loop solution is almost certainly faster (and more obvious) than either one of these. Sometimes modern does not mean better. This is one of those sometimes.

Comment: @DavidHammen Obvious is in the eye of the beholder, but performance-wise it should be equivalent with a decent optimizer.